# SCRAM-SHA-256 error while creating mongodb user from ansible

Tags: mongodb, ansible, pymongo

I am getting error while creating user from ansible for my mongo DB, I have tried many options but still not get success, I am nw to MONGO db can you please try to help me with this error.

```
  - name: Create User
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - mongodb_user:
     database: admin
     login_port: 27019
     name: srini
     password: srini@1
     roles: admin
     state: present
```

Below is the error which I am getting:-

```
$>ansible-playbook a.yml

PLAY [Create User] ******************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [mongodb_user] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: OperationFailure: command SON([('createUser', 'srini'), ('pwd', u'83990cb68048395a588a63033c2c5baa'), ('digestPassword', False), ('roles', ['admin'])]) on namespace admin.$cmd failed: Use of SCRAM-SHA-256 requires undigested passwords
 [WARNING]: The value 27019 (type int) in a string field was converted to u'27019' (type string). If this does not look like what you expect, quote the
entire value to ensure it does not change.

 [WARNING]: The value ******** (type int) in a string field was converted to u'********' (type string). If this does not look like what you expect, quote
the entire value to ensure it does not change.

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to add or update user: command SON([('createUser', 'srini'), ('pwd', u'83990cb68048395a588a63033c2c5baa'), ('digestPassword', False), ('roles', ['admin'])]) on namespace admin.$cmd failed: Use of SCRAM-SHA-256 requires undigested passwords"}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: What is your pymongo version ? There is a (still open...) [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/44970) with comments suggesting to upgrade pymongo to 3.7+.

Comment: $>python -c 'import pymongo; print (pymongo.__version__)'
3.2